# WebStorm: Why doesn't Refactor work?

Tags: refactoring, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to do Refactor on WebStorm. I mark the function name I want to refactor, make a right click --> Refactor --> Rename, then the function name is surrounded in red frame, i.e. 
[image]

and from this point I can change the name of the function. The problem is that the new name I give is not accepted by WebStorm and I can't just exit the mode of editing the name of the function and keep the new name.

Comment: please create a support ticket